# Area 51 site icon duplication

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Apparently some people are *really* involved in a certain site. I noticed this on Area 51.

[image: User with two ER tokens]

This can still be seen [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top).

<sub>For clarity, the problem is that the first icon is repeated</sub>

Comment: Where the rep for the 2nd icon (2,621) come from? It differs from the first (5,210). :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just fixed a bug where in some cases, an extra row was added to our "associations" table when a user first associated with another account. The extra row was never updated, but it was never deleted either. For example, reemrevnivek's Electronics & Robotics reputation was 2621 when he first associated his ER and A51 accounts, but his reputation increased to 5210 since then.

The extra rows have been deleted. Hopefully (i.e. assuming this is the only bug causing the problem), no more "duplicated icons" will crop up in the future.